# Vertically aligned Collection view cells with varying heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am building a collection view, every cell has a fixed width but a varying height. There should be a border of 1 px within each cell. I have tried to find a way to make them vertically align but end up with white space in between them. Also some times the cells end up on top of each other.

[image: Collection view example]

What would be the best wat to solve this problem. I have considered subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

I am currently setting the size like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: CGFloat(defaultCellSize), height: CGFloat(defaultCellSize * ratio))

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this library https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout It has handled what is required.

Comment: Looks good. Still curious to see if there is a clean simple way to do it myself though!

Comment: The repo also contains a delegate inspired by flow layout that is really easy to implement. Solved my problem!